# Button background picture from MemoryStream

Tags: c#, winforms, picturebox, memorystream

i need to apply background picture from stream (picture should be taken from database).
i have this code for obtaining image from database (stream)

```
PictureBox pictureBox = new PictureBox();
if (!list_computer_imageRow.IspicNull())
{
MemoryStream stream = new MemoryStream(list_computer_imageRow.pic);
try
{
pictureBox.Image = Image.FromStream(stream);
}
catch (Exception)
{
}
```

i try this:

```
this.button1.BackgroundImage = Image.FromStream(stream);
```

but when i run app background image does not appear, i see only button with text. where is my mistake?

Comment: "unsuccessful" is not a sufficient description of what is going wrong. Please do *precisely* describe any problems, error messages, and how/where/when they arise. Also, are you using WinForms or WPF? `PictureBox` sounds like the former, while `ImageBrush` sounds like the latter. However, handling bitmaps is fundamentally different in those two UI toolkits. Please add the appropriate tag.

Comment: *Why* can't you use it? What happens when you try? Any error messages? [Please be more specific with your question.](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/how-to-ask)

Comment: That error message means exactly what it says, namely that the identifier `stream` is out of scope where you try to use it. Where did you place the line with the button with respect to the `PictureBox`-related code? Can you show the two in context?

Comment: Quite late, but did you ever take into consideration that in order for a button to have a color, it needs to be a different button style such as Flat?